# Why does Kubernetes not find any StorageClass even though it seems to exist?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have `Bound` PVs for the storage class `local-storage` which IMO proves that the storage class exists:

```
$ kubectl get pv -n example-com
NAME               CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                            STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
db-worker-1        10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    example-com/cluster-pg-3          local-storage            2d20h
db-worker-1-loki   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    example-com/data-loki-backend-0   local-storage            14m
db-worker-2        10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    example-com/cluster-pg-1          local-storage            2d20h
db-worker-2-loki   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    example-com/data-loki-backend-2   local-storage            14m
db-worker-3        10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    example-com/cluster-pg-2          local-storage            2d20h
db-worker-3-loki   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    example-com/data-loki-backend-1   local-storage            14m
```

Also, I have PVCs for `local-storage`, some of which are `Bound` and others are `Pending`:

```
$ kubectl get pvc -n example-com
NAMESPACE    NAME                            STATUS    VOLUME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS    AGE
example-com   cluster-pg-1                    Bound     db-worker-2        10Gi       RWO            local-storage   2d20h
example-com   cluster-pg-2                    Bound     db-worker-3        10Gi       RWO            local-storage   2d20h
example-com   cluster-pg-3                    Bound     db-worker-1        10Gi       RWO            local-storage   2d20h
example-com   data-loki-backend-0             Bound     db-worker-1-loki   10Gi       RWO            local-storage   9m42s
example-com   data-loki-backend-1             Bound     db-worker-3-loki   10Gi       RWO            local-storage   9m41s
example-com   data-loki-backend-2             Bound     db-worker-2-loki   10Gi       RWO            local-storage   9m41s
example-com   data-loki-write-0               Pending                                                local-storage   8m30s
example-com   data-loki-write-1               Pending                                                local-storage   8m26s
example-com   data-loki-write-2               Pending                                                local-storage   8m17s
example-com   export-0-grafana-loki-minio-0   Pending                                                                8m26s
example-com   export-1-grafana-loki-minio-0   Pending                                                                8m17s
```

The ones that are pending say that:

```
storageclass.storage.k8s.io "local-storage" not found
```

which seems weird, because there are working PVCs in the same namespace.

But when I try to list all storage classes:

```
$ kubectl get sc --all-namespaces
No resources found
```

How is this possible?

Comment: In kubernetes documentation Each StorageClass has a provisioner that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified. local volumes could help you. [Local volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) do not currently support dynamic provisioning, however a StorageClass should still be created to delay volume binding until Pod scheduling. This is specified by the WaitForFirstConsumer volume binding mode.

Comment: Refer to this [mount options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#mount-options) and How to Use a [Local Persistent Volume?](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/#how-to-use-a-local-persistent-volume).

Comment: Aah I think I get it now; basically, I only created 6 local PVs but I have 11 PVCs and local PVs are not dynamically provisioned. Now I also understand the benefit of [OpenESB Local PV](https://openebs.io/docs/concepts/localpv), which supports dynamic PV provisioning. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you referring to the storage class?  Do you actually need a custom storage class, or can you use the cluster's default storage provisioner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kubernetes documentation Each StorageClass has a provisioner that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified. local volumes could help you. [Local volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) do not currently support dynamic provisioning, however a StorageClass should still be created to delay volume binding until Pod scheduling. This is specified by the WaitForFirstConsumer volume binding mode.

Refer to this [mount options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#mount-options) and [How to Use a Local Persistent Volume?](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/#how-to-use-a-local-persistent-volume).

As you stated, all can understand the benefit of [OpenESB Local PV](https://openebs.io/docs/concepts/localpv), which supports dynamic PV provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes a `StorageClass` is just a reference to a provisioner (either CSI-based or so called "in-tree").

You can delete any `StorageClass` at any point of time which causes all volume operations (create/delete, attach/detach) to fail.